# How do I specify nvidia runtime from docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, tensorflow, nvidia-docker

I am able to run a tensorflow container w/ access to the GPU from the command line w/ the following command

`$ sudo docker run --runtime=nvidia --rm gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu`

I would like to be able to run this container from docker-compose. Is it possible to specify the `--runtime` flag from `docker-compose.yml`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should edit `/etc/docker/daemon.json`, adding the first level key `"default-runtime": "nvidia"`, restart docker daemon (ex. `"sudo service docker restart"`) and then all containers on that host will run with nvidia runtime.

More info on `daemon.json` [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/)

Answer (score 48):

Currently (Aug 2018), NVIDIA container runtime for Docker ([nvidia-docker2](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker)) [supports Docker Compose](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#do-you-support-docker-compose).

> Yes, use Compose format 2.3 and add runtime: nvidia to your GPU service. Docker Compose must be version 1.19.0 or higher.

Example `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2.3'

services:
  nvsmi:
    image: ubuntu:16.04
    runtime: nvidia
    environment:
      - NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=all
    command: nvidia-smi
```

More [example from NVIDIA blog uses Docker Compose](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/gpu-containers-runtime/) to show how to launch multiple GPU containers with the NVIDIA Container Runtime.

Comment: This option is possible only for docker-compose v2 for now. For more info, please look at the corresponding pull request here https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/5405

Comment: This option is more elegant as it allows for better packaging using docker-compose

Comment: hm can different containers have different runtimes in one docker-compose file?

Answer (score 5):

Or better: using `systemd` and assuming the path is `/usr/libexec/oci/hooks.d/nvidia`

### Configure

```
mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/
cat > /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/nvidia-containers.conf <<EOF
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -D --add-runtime nvidia=/usr/libexec/oci/hooks.d/nvidia --default-runtime=nvidia
EOF
```

### Restart

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart docker
```

### Demo

Don't need to specify `--runtime=nvidia` since we set `default-runtime=nvidia` in the configuration step.

```
docker run --rm gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu
```

---

Solution Inspired from my [tutorial about KATA runtime](http://elegance.abdennoor.com/successfully-running-kata-containers-in-the-cloud).

Answer (score 0):

Setting the default runtime seemed the most reasonable to me. However Gabriel's answer did not work for me.

Instead I found that the nvidia container toolkit can automatically configure the `daemon.json` [1].

```bash
sudo nvidia-ctk runtime configure --runtime=docker --set-as-default
sudo service docker restart
```

This should be more future proof, since it now adds a different section to the `daemon.json`.

[1] https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/container-toolkit/1.12.1/user-guide.html